# What is the fundamental observable in casual set theory?

Tags: quantum-gravity, causality, observables

In ordinary quantum theory or string theory, the fundamental observables are correlation functions or scattering amplitude that can  be measured by particle physics experiments .

In loop quantum gravity, the fundamental observables are gravitional holonomies that can be detemined by a pair of particle spins when they reunion.

In [causal set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_sets), causal structure are taken to be fundamental as a pregeometry structure. By this, my question is what is the fundamental observables in casual set theory. What we can measure to determine the dynamical ingredients in it?